# Integrand for a set of points

Tags: integration, vectors

I need help finding what I should be integrating when the question asks to find the double integral to find the volume of the tetrahedron given the points $(0,0,0),(3,0,0),(2,1,0),(3,0,4)$. Would the integrand be $1$? Would I somehow find the limits by finding equation of the lines between the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the integral is $\int \int \int 1 \ dx \ dy \ dz$ You assess the limits so you cover the tetrahedron, based on the faces and edges

Comment: since the question asks for a double integral how would it affect the integrand and limits?

Comment: The inner integral is simply the range of $x$ at the given $y,z$, so you can do it first and be left with a double integral

Comment: @ Ross Milligan so I would have to find the equation of planes to find the limits for x, find equation of lines for y, and points for z? If so, is there not an easier way? Thanks

Comment: You are doing the $z$ integral last,so its limits are the whole range in $z$, which is $[0,4]$  Now at a given $z$ you need to find the minimum and maximum $y$.  The minimum is clearly $0$.  The maximum will be on the line $(2,1,0)$ to $(3,0,4)$.  Getting $x$ will be some work.  That is why you want the volume formula $\frac 13bh$-it is much easier.